# Python multiprocessing - how to make processes wait each other if they happen to execute same function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Ill try to keep this short:
im building a program that opens up multiple browsers in selenium, arranges them on screen and plays livestreams from different predefined channels on different stream services.

It also detects if stream is active or not, and if its inactive, it closes browser and relaunches it again(simply has to work as this way now).

So each process opens its own stream (it has open_browser function) and then watches it(this can be watch function).

Issue is, open browser function has some pyautogui stuff that has to click on certain coordinates on certain browsers, and if 2 or more browsers are getting opened in same time, browser windows may overlap each other and pyautogui may click on wrong browser and make a mess.

Can i make it work in a way that if 2 or more processes happen to execute open_browser function in same time, that they wait each other till that function is fully executed, making them queue up. I dont want to make all processes stop, i want others to continue watching, while only the ones opening browsers should wait.

Comment: It sounds like you want a single queue that each process has access to which is monitored by a separate single process which can relaunch browsers.

Comment: You create a single `lock = multiprocessing.Lock()` instance that you pass to each process and when the process needs to do the `open_browser` function it must first call `lock.acquire()` and when it's through it calls `lock.release()` or instead or acquire/release just do `with lock: code to open browser window`. But this sounds like you might be able to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing since each browser is already a process. Then just use a `threading.Lock()`.

Comment: Ive tried it now but nothing happened actually. Ive printed the lock and it still executes all processes in same time, and print says 3 different process owners at the same time. I did create the Lock in my tkinter button function, placed it in class(to which open browser function belongs) arguments, made it self.lock in my class and called it in function.
edit: nvm, ive placed now the lock in my init.main instead of my UI command function, called it in my UI class, then called it again into other class over button. Works as charm! thanks!
 @Booboo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104756/python-multiprocessing-how-to-make-processes-wait-each-other-if-they-happen-to/69109854#comment122143679_69104756) by Booboo solved it:

> You create a single `lock = multiprocessing.Lock()` instance that you pass to each process and when the process needs to do the `open_browser` function it must first call `lock.acquire()` and when it's through it calls `lock.release()` or instead or acquire/release just do with `lock: code to open browser window`. But this sounds like you might be able to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing since each browser is already a process. Then just use a `threading.Lock()`.